# Как установить Kube в Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm

Решил изучать Laravel и начать на нем что-то делать. Насколько я знаю, там по умолчанию идет Bootstrap, но мне бы хотелось вместо него использовать такой css фреймворк как [Kube](https://imperavi.com/kube). Как это <strike>можно</strike> нужно сделать?

Comment: Помоему в ларавел ничего подобного нет. Привязывай что хочешь {!! HTML::style('/path/to/bootstrap.min.css') !!}

Comment: Ты можешь использовать любой фронтэнд, какой тебе захочется. В ларавел из коробки просто даются инструменты для сборки фронта. Но это не значит, что тебе нужно их использовать. Сверстай макет, раздели на blade-шаблоны, правильно пропиши пути к ассетам и будет тебе счастье))